# Python/kivy : use key ctrl+n keyboard interface in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy-1.9.0`.
I am using 
keyboard interface.Can someone tell me how to fire event when press `ctrl+n` key? 
I am using this code but its not working.

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == 'lctrl' and keycode[1] == 'n':
        print('Event Fire')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press ctrl + n ctrl is passed in the modifiers which is a list, and n is passed in keycode which is a tuple. Try this:

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == 'n' and 'ctrl' in modifiers:
        print('Event Fire')
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to check the *modifiers* is *not an empty list* before checking for *ctrl + n*. If no checking, it will produce an error.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(class_name, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl' and text == 'n':  # Ctrl+a
        print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
        print(" - text is %r" % text)
        print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)
        print('Event Fire')
```